# Android Studio: Regex not working

Tags: android, regex, eclipse

I migrated my project from Eclipse to Android Studio and everything worked fine. In this project I have a Regex which should find all image urls in a json-object I get from an API.

This is the Regex I have:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("https?:\\/\\/[^\"]*?\\.(png|jpe?g|img)");

            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(obj.toString());
            while(matcher.find()) {
                ImageBackgroundFetcher.getInstance(mActivity).addImageToLoadingQueue(matcher.group());
            }
```

obj is the JSONObject I have with the image urls. It looks like the following and I would like to extract the url of the image (the bold marked part)
{"image":"**http:\/\/www.test.de\/media\/2015\/01\/16\/bildtitel.jpg**"}

After I migrate the project from Eclipse to Android Studio this Regex isn't working any longer. The matcher.find()-Method did not return true and Android Studio gives me a warning in the code at the regex part *"\\/\\/"* where it says "redundant character escape"

I already googled but didn't find a solution. Any ideas how to solve the problem would be great, thanks in advance ;)

Comment: don't escape the forward slash.

Comment: `"redundant character escape"` Surely the obvious first thing to try, given the error message, is remove the character escape?! What error message, of any, do you get after that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I am able to solve this issue. The correct regex is:

```
https?:\\\\/\\\\/[^\"]*?\\.(png|jpe?g|img)
```

Answer (score 16):

You can use AS function to check Regex.

Press Shortcut: Alt+Enter → check regexp
[image]

[image: Match result]]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this site to check:

http://regexr.com/

using the pattern:

```
(https?:\\/\\/.+(png|jpe?g|img))(?:")
```

and capturing the first group it should work.
Just check in java, escaping \ and / is not the same as the site i linked

Using your expression, the pattern:

```
https?:\/\/[^\\"]*?\\.(png|jpe?g|img)
```

should work too. This last string should not be escaped again. Check also your string in the original eclipse project!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I also use this site to check and it told me that my regex should work. But in Android Studio it doesnt...but I'm already able to solve the issue. View my answer below ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the way Java treats Regex, it needs String literals.  So \\ for a single \

Answer (score 0):

I was Using the static method `Regex.fromLiteral()` and it did not work as expected. After a lot of effort I found that this method does not recognize the escaped characters and treats the provided string as such.

This is my regular expression: `([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+)\.([a-zA-Z.-]+)(\/\S*)?` and it is in it's original form. without escapes.

Honestly I couldn't make it work using that method so I just ended up using this approach:

```
val pattern = Regex("""([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+)\.([a-zA-Z.-]+)(\/\S*)?""")
    return pattern.matches(text)
```

As you can see I provided my regex inside a string inside 3 quotation marks. It is the Kotlin way to say that i don't want any escaping inside this string and it is a Literal.